# How Vds is calculated here?

Tags: voltage, transistors, mosfet, current, resistance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHrgpN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is also the resistance of the Mosfet which is equal to 0.25(Ohm) I just didn't know how to add it to the circuit. We're gonna call it **Rdson**.

**First question says: Calculate Ids that passes through the transistor.**

Vcc - rIds - Rdson x Ids = 0

Ids = 12/ (0.25 + 1.25) = **8 A**

**Second question says: Calculate VDS(max)**

Vds = Ids(r + Rdson) = 8(1.5) = 12v

That's what I don't understand. Why the book included r in calculating VDS? Isn't it supposed to be:

**Vds = Ids x r**

Did the book make a mistake here?

Also, is VDS(max) the same as normal VDS?

*My problem:* How VDS(max) is calculated in this circuit? Is the way the book solved it correct?

Comment: Instead of re-asking the same question, update your original question from 1 hour ago. You can basically copy-paste this question's title + everything over the old question.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I did it, but I'm so sick of changing and writing posts all over again. I'm so in urgent in need of this information and I did all what I could to make the post readable and understandable.

Comment: *I'm so in urgent in need of this information* Hmm, realize that that remark rings bells here like **homework** and **test**. We will be extra weary of providing a straight answer as we don't want to do **your** homework for you or do **your** test for you.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie This is not my homework nor my test. This is just was an exercise I was trying to solve so that I improve. I just want my damn answer and get out of here and continue doing my other things.